# SQL Server Convert() changing data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, isnull

Why does this happen?

In the following example, when i ISNULL to compare a blank int and a blank varchar they equal each other.
When the same logic is wrapped with a convert they do not equal each other.

```
DECLARE @myint int
DECLARE @mychar VARCHAR(200)

SET @myint = null
SET @mychar = NULL

SELECT CASE when CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),iSNULL(@myint,'')) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),ISNULL(@mychar,'')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'poop'

SELECT CASE when iSNULL(@myint,'') =ISNULL(@mychar,'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'poop'`
```

The reason this is an issue is because I am creating hashkeys with several appended fields. I recently changed the data type of one field from a varchar to an int (the field only ever stores an int) and now when that field is null the generated hashkey is different because the Convert function somehow sees the data as being different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's instructive if you also print out the results of the smaller expressions:

```
DECLARE @myint int
DECLARE @mychar VARCHAR(200)

SET @myint = null
SET @mychar = NULL

SELECT CASE when CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),iSNULL(@myint,'')) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),ISNULL(@mychar,'')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'poop',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),iSNULL(@myint,'')),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),ISNULL(@mychar,''))

SELECT CASE when iSNULL(@myint,'') =ISNULL(@mychar,'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'poop',
iSNULL(@myint,''),
ISNULL(@mychar,'')
```

You should be able to see that even after the `ISNULL` checks, you end up with `@myint` replaced by `0` and `@mychar` an empty string. Why? Because `ISNULL` will always returns data of the same type as its first argument, which for `@myInt` is an `int`. And an `int` cannot store an empty string. When an empty string is converted to an `int`, it's interpreted as `0`.

And that's also what's happening in your second comparison - we're comparing an `int` to a `varchar` and since `int` has higher precedence, that's the direction that the conversion happens in and so they compare equal.

But in the first case, you're effectively forcing the data conversion to happen in the other direction. And `0` converted to a `varchar` does not become an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is all to do with [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql), and this is a documented part of SQL Server.

For [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql), the data type used is the datatype of the first value. So for `ISNULL(@int,'')`, if the value of `@int` is *`NULL`*, then then value `''` will be used. `''` however, is `varchar`, and has a **lower** data type precedence than `int`; thus it is converted to an `int`. `''` as an int is `0`. So, (assuming again than `@int` has a value of *`NULL`*) `ISNULL(@int,'') = 0` would evaluate to true.

If, however, `@int` was a (oddly) a `varchar`, then `ISNULL(@int,'')` would return `''`, not `0`. So, straight away, you can see a difference in behaviour because of the data types. *note, however, that `ISNULL(@int,'') = 0` would still evaluate to true, even if `@int` was a `varchar`, as data type precedence would again apply when resolving the expression.*

Different functions handle data type precedence differently. So, for example `COALESCE` uses the highest data type precedence in used in the function. Thus `COALESCE('a',1)` would try return an `int` (and fail). On the other hand, `ISNULL('a',1)` would return a `varchar(1)`, as that's the datatype of the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of implicit conversion. When you wrap an int in ISNULL and tell it to return an empty string there is an implicit conversion of that empty string to an int. When an empty string is converted to an int it becomes 0.

Here is what I mean.

```
DECLARE @myint int
SET @myint = null
select iSNULL(@myint,'')
```